# Redefine Statement each time while writing to Sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite

I have written a java code to take values from one table in Sqlite Database named edges and write it to another table named distances. But while writing the values to the table distances I have to redefine the Statement each time. If I don't redefine the value of Statement the loop exits after one iteration executing the code given below :

```
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

But if I redefine the Statement the loop continues as expected i.e.  the code line which I have commented out.Thank You.

```
public static Connection dbconn;
public static Statement statement;
public void solve(InputReader in,OutputWriter out) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    try
    {   
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        dbconn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/src/db.db"); 
        System.out.println("Connected"); 
        statement = dbconn.createStatement(); 
        statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from edges;"); 
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO distances (Road_Name,Start_Latitude,Start_Longitude)" +
                        "VALUES ('"+rs.getString("Road_Name")+"',"+rs.getString("Start_Latitude")+","+rs.getString("Start_Longitude")";

            //Statement statement= dbconn.createStatement(); 
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception : "+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a single operation as suggested by @pasha701 !!! It would be my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't reuse `Statement statement`, as it will close `ResultSet rs`;
2. You shouldn't concatenate data in SQL statement. Use parameters within prepared statement;
3. For better performance, auto-commit should be disabled and explicitly called after all update calls.

My suggestion:

```
public static Connection dbconn;
public static Statement qry;
public void solve(InputReader in,OutputWriter out) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    try
    {   
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        dbconn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/src/db.db"); 
        System.out.println("Connected"); 
        PreparedStatement upd = dbconn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO distances (Road_Name,Start_Latitude,Start_Longitude) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        dbconn.setAutoCommit(false);
        qry = dbconn.createStatement();
        qry.setQueryTimeout(30);
        ResultSet rs = qry.executeQuery("select * from edges;"); 
        while(rs.next())
        {
            upd.setString(1, rs.getString("Road_Name"));
            upd.setString(2, rs.getString("Start_Latitude"));
            upd.setString(3, rs.getString("Start_Longitude"));
            upd.executeUpdate();
        }
        dbconn.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception : "+e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Better make such operation with a single SQL operation:

```
INSERT INTO distances (Road_Name, Start_Latitude, Start_Longitude)
SELECT Road_Name, Start_Latitude, Start_Longitude
FROM edges
```

Or use two Statements, one for `Select`, second for `Insert`.