# Connecting to SQLite from Java. Getting some disorder in commands

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a factory class which "builds" different database connectors using one and the same interface. I have no trouble with `MySQL` and `Postgre`, but I do get some troubles when I try to connect and run some queries against `SQLite` database. So, this is the disorder I see:

```
SQL db = SQL_Factory.build("SQLite");
System.out.println("BEFORE CONNECT");
db.connect();
System.out.println("BEFORE SHOW");
List<String> tables = db.show_tables();
```

and inside `connect()` method I have these debugging commands:

```
try{
    cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + db_path);
    System.out.println("CONNECTED");
} 
....
```

As a result of running the code I expected to see this in the console:

```
BEFORE CONNECT
CONNECTED
BEFORE SHOW
```

However, what I see looks rather strange:

```
BEFORE CONNECT
BEFORE SHOW
CONNECTED
```

Indeed, I'm getting a lot of other errors, but it's quite obvious, that all of them result from this disorder - `CONNECTED` status appears long after other commands that need this connection to be set. So, I wonder where this async behaviour may come from and how to repair it? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Well, on the official [page](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) I see extremely strange lines of code:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // <- WTF?????????

statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists person");
```

So, is it really necessary to set timeout?? It looks like rubbish.

Comment: Since I can't figure out where the apparent asynchronicity comes from, I only reply to the second question. And, no, the query timeout is not even remotely necessary, at least for the statement being executed in the reported code.

Comment: 30 seconds to set connection, Carl!! 30 seconds. Goodness!

Comment: Whatever example I've seen here at stackoverflow, they are always using timeout. Proof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769031/redefine-statement-each-time-while-writing-to-sqlite-database , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098939/how-do-you-select-from-multiple-tables-in-sqlite-in-java etc. etc.

Comment: "My average Horstmann"  ( author of  [Core Java series](http://horstmann.com/corejava.html) ) does not. Nor have I ever used it in the plain jdbc usage. I think it's a matter of caution in order to avoid a program hang (default timeout is... infinite). Moreover, checking for a timeout being hit, with an adquate granularity, requires you to handle a SQLTimeoutException . Unless the table dropping operation takes ages to complete (which I doubt) there should be no need to explicitly set a timeout.

Comment: If it is so, why then I'm getting this disorder? PS, I'm using Ubuntu. May be it is OS specific.

Comment: And by the way, this error - https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/81/the-method-getobject-in-rs-class-processes - is still there. All this make me think that this java library is the worst, I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick-and-dirty test.

Db.java

```
class Db {
Connection conn;



public Db() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



void connect(String dbPath) throws SQLException {
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbPath);
    }
    finally {
    }
}



void doStuff() throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        // statement.setQueryTimeout(30);
        statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists person");
    }
    finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
    }
}



void disconnect() throws SQLException {
    try {
        conn.close();
    }
    finally {
        conn = null;
    }
}
}
```

Main.java

```
class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Db db = new Db();
    System.out.println("b4 connect");
    db.connect("justATest");
    System.out.println("connected");
    db.doStuff();
    System.out.println("done some stuff, disconnecting....");
    db.disconnect();
    System.out.println("disconnected");
}
}
```

Using jdk 1.8 over windows7, maven 3.3 and sqlite 3.8.11.2, the console output is as follows

[image]

Unfortunately I have no means of carrying out tests on a different OS.

Comment: Then, I think it is OS specific or version specific. I'm using the last one - sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar